# Yii2 Class 'DateRangePicker' not found

Tags: yii2, yii2-grid

Answer

php composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker "@dev"

I want filter in GridView::widget by date range

But I got error "Class 'DateRangePicker' not found"

Helpres does not find this module

```
   [
                                                'attribute' => 'Date',
                                                'label' => 'Data',

                                                'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                                                    return $model->create_at;
                                                },
                                                'filter' => DateRangePicker::widget([
                                                                                            'model'=>$searchModel,
                                                                                            'attribute' => 'createdAt',
                                                                                            'pluginOptions'=> [
                                                                                                    'locale'=>['format' => 'Y-m-d'],
                                                                                                    "opens"=>"left",
                                                                                            ]
                                                                               ])
                                        ]
```

How to properly filter by date range?

Comment: Have you `imported` this widget?

Comment: I don't know how to import it

Comment: At the top of your view file, you can see `import` section where you import all widgets and components. Just type underneath a new line with `use path/to/the/file/DateRangePicker;`

Comment: Are you using `kartik` DateRangePicker? if so, that will be the line you need: `use kartik\daterange\DateRangePicker;`

Comment: I need token to install it.    Install of kartik-v/yii2-date-range failed
  - Installing kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker (dev-master fada92b): Cloning fada92bc50

Comment: That is out of scope question, try to create a new one with problem you have like can't install `DateRangePicker`.

Comment: Failed to clone https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-date-range.git, git was not found, check that it is installed and in your PATH
   env.

Comment: use composer to update your project dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install this package

```
php composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-date-range "dev-master"
```

and add `use kartik\daterange\DateRangePicker;`